# Передача переменных из функции python

Tags: python

Ребята подскажите реально ли передать переменную из функции в другую функцию python?
Пример:

```
def Func1(){
    var1 = 'data'
}

def Func2(){
    print (var1)
}
```

Реально ли реализовать такую штуку как нибудь, без глобальных переменных?

Comment: Возврат значения из функции через return вам не подходит по каким-то причинам?

Comment: Не подходит, так-как функция уже возвращает значение...

Comment: @user238428 вы можете tuple вернуть: просто через запятую верните значения

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы передать аргумент в другую функцию, она должна как минимум его принимать. Можно из первой функции вызвать вторую с нужным аргументом.

```
def Func1():
    var1 = 'data'
    Func2(var1)

def Func2(var1):
    print(var1)
Func1()
```

Ещё первая функция может вернуть значение с помощью return. Это самое значение можно сразу передать в вызов второй функции, не создавая глобальных переменных.

```
def Func1():
    var1 = 'data'
    return var1

def Func2(var1):
    print(var1)
Func2(Func1())
```

P.S. В Python вместо операторных скобок используются отступы.